# Regex to match parts of the filename with multiple extensions

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write the regex to match

- `filename_with_multiple_exts` as the first group and
- `aaa.bbb.user.js` as the second group

of the following string:

```
filename_with_multiple_exts.aaa.bbb.user.js
```

This is what I have currently ([test](https://regexr.com/4q6r4)):

```
(\.([^\.]*[\.])*)([^\.]+)$
```

But it isn't exactly what I'm searching for.

Comment: Maybe `([^.]*)\.(.*)` which is just splitting with the first `.`? See https://regex101.com/r/NAc2rg/1

Comment: What regex tool/language are you using?

Comment: It what way(s) isn't it exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: @ScottHunter Periods, I don't need them. Click the link and hover the mouse over the selection to see them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, it looks perfect for my use case. It could be an answer, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may split the string at the first dot using

```
([^.]*)\.(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NAc2rg/1). Anchors are not required, you might just want to tune the regex if you operate on individual lines, if not, it will work as is.

**Details**

- `([^.]*)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars other than dots
- `\.` -  a dot
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any 0 or more char (usually, other than line breaks, but that varies from regex flavor to flavor).

See a [visual graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%5B%5E.%5D*)%5C.(.*)), too:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Isn't it too bold to ask you to show how to match the extensions without the filename? I can use `\..*`, but it includes the period, not really good.

Comment: @johnc.j. Depending on the regex engine, you may use `(?<=\.).*` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/NAc2rg/2)) or `\.\K.*` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/NAc2rg/3)). You may also use `\.(.*)` and grab Group 1 value, again, this might require some feature/code.